# the suggestions about restoring the directories under /var?

Tags: directory, restore

Terribly sorry for this basic question, I'm a newbie to the linux world.

Currently I have a RHEL 7.5 machine which should normally have the following stuff under /var directory: adm, cache, crash, db, empty, games, gopher, kerberos, lib, local, lock, log, mail, nis, opt, preserve, run, spool, tmp, yp

and now the directories: "kerberos", "local", "mail", "nis", "opt", "preserve", "yp" were missed.

This RHEL 7.5 machine is used to run Cassandra.

After some googling and thinking, I collected 2 critical options to restore these missing directories:

1. restore from other RHEL's backup(there's more than one such RHEL 7.5 machines running Cassandra and they all have almost the same config., system, directories, accounts and files.)
2. using the RHEL installation ISO(rescue mode).

I examined other RHEL machines (which are 99% identical to the one that missed directories) to see the importance of the missing directories and found that the "kerberos", "local", "nis", "opt","preserve","yp" are empty and the size are 4.0K respectively. Only the "mail" directory do have some user accounts' data in sub-directories.

So I assumed that recreating the "mail" directory might be the most important task despite I'm not sure about how to rebuild the "mail".(seemed that other directories can be created manually and I know it's easy.)

Can anyone give me some hints about how to restore directories with minimum impact to the current system? I hope I don't need to reinstall the whole system...

Thanks in advance!

*Added:

Currently, I got some output listed below,

1. `df -h`

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   87G  4.3G   78G   6% /
devtmpfs                16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   16G   33M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                   16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2              976M  112M  798M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel-home  2.0T  763G  1.1T  41% /home
tmpfs                  3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

2. `df /var`

```
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root  90695520 4479244  81586160   6% /
```

3. the result of `journalctl -b |grep /var` including the following messages:(some of them are repeating)

```
rsyslogd[1337]: $WorkDirectory: /var/lib/rsyslog can not be accessed, probably does not exist - directive ignored [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2181 ]
postfix/sendmail[1387]: fatal: chdir /var/spool/postfix: No such file or directory
```

4. the output of `journalctl |grep /var/log` only showed 4 messages:

```
auditd[792]: Could not open dir /var/log/audit (No such file or directory)
systemd[1]: Starting Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg...
systemd[1]: Started Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
sa1[807]: Cannot open /var/log/sa/sa27: No such file or directory
```

It seemed that the situation is still confusing due to insufficient clues from logs...
but again, I still appreciate everyone's assistance.

Comment: It would help to know how you ended up in this situation - please edit your question and include what steps lead up to this.

Comment: thank you Panki. The trouble is this situation isn't caused by me and it is too difficult to trace back. I checked the bash history but couldn't (or maybe due to lack of linux knowledge) found any useful clues. Really sorry.

Comment: Try to examine the output of `journalctl -b` (all syslog messages for the current boot). What does `df /var` output?

Comment: @U.Windl thanks for the hints. however, I dont see clues that are helpful, guess this situation already happened long time ago therefore the traces are hard to find.